# Straight line draw animation how doing it?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I am trying to do something simple yet i haven't found a way to do it in blender that is animating the drawing of borders of a shape (rectangles, triangles...) you can see an example on youtube of the result i am trying to achieve :
[How to Animate Shape Borders in Adobe After Effects CC (2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHhg-DmkikA)

If anyone has a good technique to do it or a blender file it would be cool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Bezier Curve and make it any shape you want to. <kbd>SHFT</kbd> +<kbd>A</kbd> > Curve > Bezier.

[image: Add Curve]

"Extrude" it to add some width.

[image]

Then Animate the start and/or end of the Bevel Factor. Hover your mouse over the Start or End input box of the Curve press <kbd>I</kbd> move the Playhead in the Timeline, change the value and hover your mouse over the Start or End input box press <kbd>I</kbd> again.

[image]